# How do (which) things need to be bend and twisted here?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

This is more a general 3D modeling problem I came along while replicating things to figure out what is possible using Blender and what is not. This problem can probably easily be solved, but I am simply not figuring out how. I'd like to get #1, but #2 is more or less the best result I come up with... Maybe someone can tell me how things need to be bend and twisted here.

(There is a .blend file at the bottom if someone wants to chime in...)

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your object is not vertical :

[image: your object]

If you modelize your object like this :

[image: object in edit mode]

And add a *Simple Deform* modifier like this :

[image: simple deform modifier]

You will obtain this :

[image: final render]

Does it help ?

Comment: It's not that simple. The upper part in #1 is vertical like yours and seems somewhat coplanar with ZX plane. Its bottom part, though, is more like mine in #2 and slightly rotated. In general I think your upper part and my bottom part combined would look like #1, but I fail to get that... (I had a non-rotated mesh first, too.)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean by _slightly rotated_ ... Maybe, you should use the _Vertex Group_ field in the _Simple Deform_ field to apply your modifier only on a part of your object...